# Perl: Number every instance of a word in a text file

Tags: perl, text

I need to edit a text file that is formatted something like:

```
> Word text text text text
Text
Text
> Word text text text text
Text
Text
```

And make it look like:

```
>Word1 text text text text
Text
Text
>Word2 text text text text
Text
Text
```

Basically, I need to modify every instance of the string " Word" and turn it into "Word" followed by a number corresponding to the number of instances the string has appeared in the text file so far. I'm new to perl and have no idea what I'm doing. Here's what I have:

```
$file = "test.txt";

my %count;
my $word = " Word";

#Open and read data
open (FILE, "<$file") or die "Cannot open $file: $!\n";
@lines= <FILE>;
foreach my $word{
    my $count++;
}
close FILE;

my $counter = my $count + 1;
my $curr_ct = my $counter - my $count;

#Open same file for editing now
open (STDOUT, ">$file") or die "Cannot open $file: $!\n";


while (my $count > 0){
    s/ Word/Word$curr_ct/
    my $count--;
    my $curr_ct = my $counter - my $count;
    print;
}

close STDOUT;
```

Comment: `my` creates a new variable, so `my $count++;`, `my $count + 1`, `my $counter - my $count` and `my $count--;` make no sense.

Comment: `foreach my $word{ my $count++; }` is missing the list of things over which to loop!

Comment: `open FILE, ...` should be `open my $FILE, ...`. Don't use global vars for nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason to use `(?{ })`. When you use `/e`, the substitution expression is evaluated as Perl code for every match. That's all you need here.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $word = 'Word';

my $count;
while (<>) {
    s/\b\Q$word\E\b/ $word . ++$count /eg;
    print;
}
```

5.10 introduced `\K` which can make the key line even shorter!

```
s/\b\Q$word\E\b\K/ ++$count /eg;
```

Other improvements:

- The `\b` make it so `sword` or `wordy` aren't matched.
- The `\Q`..`\E` make it so `$word` can safely contain non-word characters.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a zero-width [code evaluation expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic%3a-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression) assertion, eg: `(?{...})` within the regex to increase the count value on each match, then use that count in the substitution side:

Note that code eval expressions are considered experimental, according to the docs.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $word = 'Word';
my $file = 'file.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

my $count;

while (<$fh>){
    s/$word(?{$count++})/$word$count/g;
    print;
}
```

Input:

```
> Word text text text text
Text
Text
> Word text text text text
Text
Text
```

Output:

```
> Word1 text text text text
Text
Text
> Word2 text text text text
Text
Text
```

Comment: `local our` should be used instead of `my` for variable used within `(?{ })` or `(??{ })` but declared outside of the `(?{ })` or `(??{ })`.

Comment: There's no need for fancy experimental stuff. This will do the same thing `s/$word\K/ ++$count /eg`

Comment: @ikegami, why? They can be closured or something?

Comment: @Vadim Pushtaev, That's exactly it. They capture when the pattern is compiled, so they suffer from the same problem as named subs inside of other subs. `perl -E'sub f { my $x = shift; "" =~ /(?{ say $x })/ } f("abc"); f("def");'`  [uh... this works now. It doesn't work on older version of Perl, though]